# SharePoint Content Query Web Part - Ignoring Current Level

Tags: sharepoint

Consider this SharePoint site hierarchy:

```
- Site Collection
 - Site1
     - Subsite1
         - AnotherSubsite1
             - Page1
             - Page2
         - AnotherSubsite2
     - Subsite2
         - Page3
         - Page4
 - Site2
```

You can assume that every Site in the above hierarchy has a default page.

If I place a CQWP on Site1's default page, can I instruct it to start getting data one level below where it was placed? i.e. ignore the page/site it's currently on, so that it returns:

```
     - Subsite1
         - AnotherSubsite1
             - Page1
             - Page2
         - AnotherSubsite2
     - Subsite2
         - Page3
         - Page4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would extend the CQWP and then hook up my own ProcessDataDelegate to remove the data that's not required. For example:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProcessDataDelegate += ProcessItems;
}

public DataTable ProcessItems(DataTable data)
{
    // Query the DataTable and remove unnecessary information
}
```

The WebId column in `data` is the GUID for the SPWeb object of each returned item. Look up [SPWeb.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.id.aspx) of the sites you no longer want and then remove these rows. Note that the GUIDs in the WebId column are upper-case and in "D" format as described in [Guid.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx).

Remember to use `AcceptChanges()` at the end to ensure the DataTable is updated.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I could easily get a reference to the current site and exclude it

Comment: A quick look with Reflector shows that the CQWP isn't designed to support multiple URLs. I think going down that road would be long and painful.

Comment: Gotcha, your approach for using the GUID of the SPWeb object would be much cleaner